# SharePoint 2013 - Increase Document Preview Panel Width and Height

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, document-library, preview

Looking for some help here with the Document Preview Panel. I need to increase the width and height of it. See an image below:

[image]

I want to increase the width and height of this so that the document preview is bigger.

Thoughts?